# OS X El Capitan - How do I specify individual sets of Hot Corners for different Virtual Desktops?

Tags: macos, desktop

I would like to have one virtual desktop where I have the "show desktop" hot corner, and second one where this is disabled, so that I do not always have to change the settings.

Can I customise virtual desktops with individual hot corners, or is there only one global setting for all virtual desktops?

Answer (score 1):

Hot corners are independent of Spaces & are unaware of which Space you're in.

I would say 'it can't be done' but it would be nice to discover I'm wrong :-)

Comment: You can add a key to it, such as the command key + hot corner to stop accidental activation.

Comment: oh, wow, I never spotted that… though I haven't changed my hot corners in 10 years...